# Running Qt application on Raspberry pi

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, raspberry-pi4

I was able to install PyQt5 on raspberry pi.
But was not able to run the python script.I do get the following error
*ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtQml'*

When I execute the command pip list, I get the following info
Package       Version

---

pip           21.3
pkg_resources 0.0.0
PyQt5         5.15.5
PyQt5-sip     12.9.0
setuptools    40.8.0

The following is a simple python script

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
engine.quit.connect(app.quit)
engine.load('main.qml')
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

The following is the main.qml file

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 500
    title: "HelloApp"
    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Hello World"
        font.pixelSize: 24
    }
}
```

I am using python version 3.7.3
I created the virtual environment and activated it as below:

```
python3 -m venv testEnv
source testEnv/bin/activate
```

I installed pyqt5 in the environment using the command
pip3 install pyqt5

I tried installing by giving the command

```
pip3 install pyqt5-tools
```

It was taking lot of time and It looked like it was downloading all available versions.
Then I tried the below command

```
pip3 install pyqt5-tools~=5.15.4.3.2
```

When the following command was executed, I got the following error.

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting pyqt5-tools~=5.15.4.3.2
  Using cached pyqt5_tools-5.15.4.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
Collecting pyqt5==5.15.4
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.4.tar.gz (3.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing wheel metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyqt5-plugins<5.15.4.3,>=5.15.4.2.2 (from pyqt5-tools) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyqt5-plugins<5.15.4.3,>=5.15.4.2.2
```

How can we check which version of pyQt5-tools needs to be installed?

Comment: what is the output of `python -c "from PyQt5.QtCore import PYQT_VERSION_STR; print('PyQt5 version', PYQT_VERSION_STR)"` after activate virtualenv?

Comment: For QML, you may also need to install [pyqt5-tools](https://pypi.org/project/pyqt5-tools/)

Comment: When I execute the command 
python -c "from PyQt5.QtCore import PYQT_VERSION_STR; print('PyQt5 version', PYQT_VERSION_STR)" 
I get
PyQt5 version 5.15.5

Comment: I will give a try installing pyqt5-tools and come back. Just a query, why is there a need to install it??
When I installed pyqt5 in the environment on Windows, it ran fine. There was no need for me to install pyqt5-tools

Comment: @bfris I tried installing pyqt5-tools. What could be wrong??

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you are using pyqt5 libraries, and simultaneously you are using qml file which is différent language and has a différents libraries and dependecies,
There is 2 cases
Case 1: If you run raspbian buster :
you need to download the source code of Qt from thier site and it's configuration and compile and build it from source code and finaly install it (Qt 5.12.10 is recommended as you use python with qml) (search in google how to install qt 5.12.10 on rapberry pi as it's a long process and a little bit difficult), then you can run your code.
Case 2: if you run the new raspbian bullseye 2022 , then it' s verry easy , you should just install it by using the command shown here:
Bullseye OS

```
$ sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev qtchooser.    
$ sudo apt-get install qt5-qmake qtbase5-dev-tools.
$ sudo apt-get install qtcreator.
$ sudo apt-get install qtdeclarative5-dev.
```

It will install the new qt version 5.15.2 and you can work with python and qml.